# How can I get confidence intervals for fixed effects using the rlmer function (robustlmm package)?

Tags: r, mixed-model, confidence-interval, robust

I need to fit a linear mixed model but my dependent variable is right-skewed with some big outliers. Thus I used the `rlmer` function of the `robustlmm` package. it works quite nicely, however what I am missing now is confidence intervals for the fixed effects. Is anyone working with this package and has some tips for me? Otherwise I would also be interested in other packages to fit robust linear mixed models.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- *Wald confidence intervals*: these assume that the sampling distribution *of the parameters* is multivariate Normal (a much weaker assumption than that the conditional distribution of the *residuals* is Normal). They are relatively easily to compute (for the fixed-effects parameters) by extracting the parameter values (`fixef()`) and the standard errors (`sqrt(diag(vcov()))`) and computing $\beta \pm z \cdot \sigma$ ...

Example:

```
library(robustlmm)
r <- rlmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), sleepstudy)

confint.rlmerMod <- function(object,parm,level=0.95) {
     beta <- fixef(object)
     if (missing(parm)) parm <- names(beta)
     se <- sqrt(diag(vcov(object)))
     z <- qnorm((1+level)/2)
     ctab <- cbind(beta-z*se,beta+z*se)
     colnames(ctab) <- stats:::format.perc(c((1-level)/2,(1+level)/2),
                                           digits=3)
     return(ctab[parm,])
 }
 confint(r)
 ##                  2.5 %    97.5 %
 ## (Intercept) 235.575485 269.27845
 ## Days          9.211197  12.04305
```

- if you think the Wald intervals are likely to be nonsymmetric on the original scale, it might be possible to compute confidence intervals on another scale, e.g. the log scale, and back-transform.
- I don't think that profile likelihood confidence intervals are an option; at the very least you'd have to follow through the theory for robust linear models and see if there was a robust-likelihood analogue that followed the same asymptotic theory.
- the same problem applies for parametric bootstrapping.
- nonparametric bootstrapping is a possibility.  See e.g. [Confidence intervals on predictions for a non-linear mixed model (nlme)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231074/confidence-intervals-on-predictions-for-a-non-linear-mixed-model-nlme) , [Non-linear mixed model (nlme) with nested random effect, do not know how to include nested random effect when bootstrapping](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232928/non-linear-mixed-model-nlme-with-nested-random-effect-do-not-know-how-to-incl/232949#232949)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already did that myself, but I am not so happy with Wald confidence intervals in this situation, as the normality assumption is obviously violated and my distribution is not symmetric...

Comment: see edits.  A non-symmetric response distribution doesn't imply that the Wald CIs are bad ...

Comment: Thank you for expanding your answer! I was also thinking about bootstrapping, but I was/am unsure how to do that correctly in this situation, incorporating the random effects etc. I will have a closer look at your links and see if I manage! It would be interesting also for comparison with the Wald confidence intervals.     About your suggestion to calculate the CIs on another scale: There I see the problem with the interpretation. The model is for a surgery trial and the surgeons need to be able to interpret the results - many of them do not have an in-depth knowledge about statistics.

Comment: Hi all! @BenBolker, I am using robustlmm and I will use your code to calculate confidence intervals. I was wondering if I have to give some specific reference if I use your method to calculate the confidence intervals since I am not using any package. By the way, I read a lot of comments from you everywhere, and I have to tell you THANK YOU VERY MUCH for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: I think that some generic reference to Wald confidence intervals would be sufficient ...

Comment: One last doubt, if possible @BenBolker. What could I cite to say that confidence intervals are more reliable than p-values using robust linear mixed-effect models? Or I don't need to justify that?

Answer (score 3):

It is also now possible to obtain confidence intervals of rlmerMod objects using the [effects](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effects/vignettes/effectsMethods.pdf) package.

Example:

```
library(robustlmm)
library(effects)

r <- rlmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), sleepstudy)
as.data.frame(effect("Days",r))

###   Days      fit       se    lower    upper
###      0 252.4270 8.597854 235.4601 269.3938
###      2 273.6812 8.161895 257.5747 289.7877
###      4 294.9355 7.967757 279.2120 310.6589
###      7 326.8168 8.161895 310.7103 342.9234
###      9 348.0711 8.597854 331.1042 365.0379
```

Comment: one doubt, How should I specified in this package if I want confidence intervals for two fixed factors and their interaction? When I specified the interaction term I get multiple rows for each level-combination between the fixed factors, but I don't want that. I want just the C.I for each fixed factor and the interaction. Do you know how to do this? I checked `help` for the package but I can't get what I want. If I use the code proposed by Ben Bolker, I get what I want, but I wanted to check if with the package I could get the same. Thanks!